# Creating an app with a secured performing service the Microsoft way

Tags: .net, web-services, mobile, wcf

This week I want to start a greater app project that is expected to handle much data. The app will provide an interactive forum, a media library that allows streaming and a task module with push notifications.

The forum data and the videos should host on a server and be provided through a service, securely.

Since I'm mainly a C# programmer and love the EntityFramework I decided to build the app in Xamarin.Forms targeting `netstandard2.0` with the `EntityFramework.Core` (we will barely need any special UI functionality besides the things Xamarin.Forms offers). I also want to build a WCF service that uses the EntityFramework on the servers side. It should handle posting in the forum as well as providing temporary video URLs from the media library.

The media library will provide paid content, so we need maximum security. The data streams of the service will burn, because of much transfer data, so we also need maximum performance. However, security over performance. The conditions require to handle 50k active users at the same time.

My questions are:

- What transfer protocol should I choose for the WCF service and why?
- The server will also host an IIS for the website of the app, should I host the service on IIS or should I build an traditional WCF service that is hosted by Windows itself?
- What is the best way to ensure the WCF service can only be reached by the app? Since Xamarin uses Mono, people could decompile the app and read its source code very easily. I need a proper authentication that would nobody allow to bypass the app and communicate with our service, directly.

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: Tech recommendations tend to be off topic (see: [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Requests for Recommendations?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)). Regarding the last point: don't authenticate your software, but authenticate your users. You cannot prevent tampering/decompiling of your app regardless of technology used. At most you can make it difficult. So the better approach is to move the trust barrier into your backend. If an API request does not come from an authorized/logged in user, you can drop the request.

Comment: @gnat I see, indeed this is a green field question that had a very broad part in it. Thus I removed parts of the question that ask if this is the right part, since many people can involve opinions to what the best is to build this project on. Instead I want to focus on the service and its communication with my app.

Comment: @amon Thank's amon. The app should work without forcing any registration. As best we can bind the user to his/her google/apple account. Since this app won't have a web platform I fear any third party can build a web platform that communicates with our service. What exactly could I do about it?

Comment: You need to accept that your service is public. It has to be designed so that it is idiotproof and stands up under abuse, just like a web site; your app is just a layer on top of it. So how would you deal with the fear that a third party would (ab)use a web site of yours?

Comment: @JohnWu I want to deal with it by finding a way to prevent any third party software to communicate with it. Since I know the app can be decompiled by any third party I wonder if there is any way besides making it hard. Any step that can give my service a proper validation would require a method to generate such measures for the successful validation on the app that can be copied from anybody in their own software. Is there even a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking that a mobile app, without any physical security, serve as a trusted application within your overall solution. Sorry. There is no mechanism to ensure that trust, at least none that has withstood the test of time (and hackers).

The way you'd typically secure a trusted application is with a client certificate. You could include the certificate as a file in your app's installer, and configure your WCF client to use it. But then any user could go through his device's memory and get the certificate and use it himself.

You could secure the certificate with a password, and bake the password into your code, but a hacker can reverse engineer your application and retrieve it.

To secure that password in a physically insecure location would be impossible without something like [white box cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-white-box-implementation-of-a-cryptographic-algorithm). However, all attempts at white box cryptography [have been broken](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/386/differences-between-white-box-cryptography-and-code-obfuscation), and [may be literally impossible](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/105) the way we do ciphers, at least for now.

So this is what I'd recommend:

1. Despite the above, use a client cert with a password. Even if it can be thwarted, it requires effort, and that effort implies intent, for legal purposes.
2. Include a clause in your terms of service that prohibits reverse engineering your application or misusing the web service.
3. Have the server issue a unique security token per install, perhaps a [MAC digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) of the device's fingerprint, including the device's [UDID](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-get-device-infoudid-model-name-os-version-in-xamarin-ios/). Make it expensive to get a token, e.g. force the client to perform a million hashes of a nonce, that sort of thing. This makes it hard for a hacker to harvest tokens en masse.
4. Monitor your service for nefarious activity.
5. When malicious activity is detected, black list the security token and stop accepting its calls.
6. Design your API so that sensitive functions are kept server-side. For example, instead of exposing a `SetHighScore` method, have the server set the high score automatically when a game is completed.

That is probably the best you can do, and probably adequate for a normal mobile app.